# craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables() loads the correct template but does not pass in the variables

Tags: templating, routes, variable

everybody!

`setRouteVariables()` doesn't appear to be working for me.  If I boil my controller function down to just this:

```
public function actionSubmitForm() {
    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables([
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ]);
}
```

and my `<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">` contains the following (among other inputs):

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="directoryForms/submitForm">
```

it hits the correct endpoint and then reloads the appropriate template, but it doesn't give me access to the `{{ foo }}` variable in that template.  It just tells me `Variable "foo" does not exist`.  I know it's hitting the right controller endpoint because if I `die()` there it dies as expected.

Any thoughts?  I've really boiled this one down as far as I can.  I must be missing something obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess, but something else (another plugin?) is redirecting/interfering with the request of the request and not letting it continue as you're expecting?

Comment: Ah, I do have custom routes set for this plugin via registerSiteRoutes()!  How does that change how I proceed?  I'd like to pass these variables back through that custom site route.  (My full use case is filling in bad user input on validation failure)

Comment: Alrighty, I've got it now.  Thanks for the push in the right directory, Brad.  I ended up routing directly to a template rather than an action which loads a template.  I didn't even realize that could be done!

Comment: Would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone else in the future?

Comment: Of course!  Thanks for all you do in the community, Brad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to load the template directly rather than routing to the controller first.  Essentially, in my `registerSiteRoutes()` function I replaced this:

```
"payment" => ['action' => 'someController/doPayment']
```

with

```
"payment" => 'templateDir/core/payment'
```

I didn't even realize you could do this in `registerSiteRoutes()`!